# onAnimationEnd is not getting called, onAnimationStart works fine

Tags: android, animation, popupwindow

I've a ScrollView in the PopupWindow. I'm animating ScrollView contents using TranslateAnimation.

When animation starts, the onAnimationStart listener is called but the onAnimationEnd is not getting called. Any ideas ?

Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:background="@drawable/popup_window_bg"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <View
     android:layout_width="@dimen/toolbar_padding_left"
     android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"/>
  <ScrollView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+web/toolbar"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:scrollbars="none"
     android:visibility="invisible">
    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical">

       ...

    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Animation code :

```
mToolbar = mPopupContents.findViewById( R.web.toolbar );
TranslateAnimation anim =
    new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, -60, 0);
anim.setDuration(1000);
anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation a) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "---- animation start listener called"  );
        }
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation a) {}
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation a) {
            Log.d(LOGTAG, "---- animation end listener called"  );
        }
    });
mToolbar.startAnimation(anim);
```

**Update** : I verified that the onAnimationEnd is called but it is called after some delay (provided you don't start the new animation during that time).

Comment: Can you test to define it inside an XML file and see if it's working there?

Comment: Looked at the API and it's telling me: **Notifies the end of the animation. This callback is not invoked for animations with repeat count set to INFINITE.**

Comment: Already tried defining this in xml (without setting listener, coz I don't know how to do that), but no luck :(

Comment: I'm not repeating the animation, setRepeatCount is not called and the default values is 0.

Comment: Put a log on onAnimationRepeat just to be sure.

Comment: Already tried that but no luck.

Comment: Does the animation seem to visually complete? Does the animation actually occur at all, or is onAnimationStart the only thing called?

Comment: Animation starts successfully and its visible as well but after some steps it stops.

Comment: try "adb logcat -v time" to show the time of calling onAnimationStart and onAnimationEnd.  Could you paste some result according above codes? thanks

Answer (score 62):

`AnimationEnd` is not reliable. If you don't want to rewrite your code with custom views that override OnAnimationEnd, use `postDelayed`.

Here's some example code:

```
final FadeUpAnimation anim = new FadeUpAnimation(v);
anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
anim.setDuration(1000);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        v.clearAnimation();
        //Extra work goes here
    }
}, anim.getDuration());
v.startAnimation(anim);
```

While it MAY seem ugly, I can guarantee it's very reliable. I use it for ListViews that are inserting new rows while removing with animation to other rows. Stress testing a listener with AnimationEnd proved unreliable. Sometimes `AnimationEnd` was never triggered. You might want to reapply any transformation in the `postDelayed` function in case the animation didn't fully finish, but that really depends on what type of animation you're using.

Comment: Thank you so much, @ShortFuse. I was struggling with setting a view's visibility to `View.VISIBLE` in `onAnimationStart()` which did not work for some android versions. After reading your answer, I ended up with this:
`workThatWouldGoInOnAnimationStart();`
`view.postDelayed(workThatWouldGoInOnAnimationEnd(), anim.getDuration());`
`view.startAnimation(anim);`

Answer (score 12):

Make sure that **you are USING** `view.startAnimation(Animation)` 
**AND NOT** `view.setAnimation(Animation)`. This simple confusion may be a problem.

Answer (score 10):

After I don't remember how may posts read and days spent finding out a solution for this issue I discovered that if the object to move is not on the Screen region (for example is positioned out of the screen coords) OnAnimationEnd callback is not getting called. Probably the animation fails just after started (start method is called, I coded a listener) but nothing is wrote into logcat. Maybe this is not exactly your case but this finally solved my problem and hope it can help you too.

Answer (score 3):

Also, when using animations, don't forget the `setFillAfter()` to `true`.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setFillAfter(boolean)

If fillAfter is true, the transformation that this animation performed will persist when it is finished. Defaults to false if not set. Note that this applies when using an AnimationSet to chain animations. The transformation is not applied before the AnimationSet itself starts.

```
anim.setFillAfter(true);
mToolbar.startAnimation(anim);
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone stumbling upon this question: Consider switching over to using the Property Animation system instead http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html

I've had several problems with the old way of animating a fade-in/out on a view (through AlphaAnimation). OnAnimationEnd was not being called etc ... With the Property Animation all those problems were resolved.

If you want to support API<11 devices, Jake Wharton's https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me in a scenario that isn't described in other answers. Tried this and it didn't work:

```kotlin
ValueAnimator.ofInt(currentHeight, desiredHeight).apply {
     duration = 500
     addListener { 
         doOnEnd {
             Log.d(TAG, "animate: animation ended")
         }
     }
     start()
}
```

Changing to this resolved the issue. Unfortunately can't tell why.

```kotlin
ValueAnimator.ofInt(currentHeight, desiredHeight).apply {
     duration = 500
     doOnEnd {
           Log.d(TAG, "animate: animation ended")
     }
      start()
}
```

Comment: This saved my day, but I would like to understand why 

This same issue was happening to me, but at the start of the animation. I used `doOnStart{ }` and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The delay is probably due to the anim.setDuration(1000) or if you are doing this on a thread, then probably due to context switching. Try manipulating the delay time and see if you notice any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use overridePendingAnimation(int,int).
i.e.
overridePendingAnimation(0,0)

It will override your default animation and then you can define you own animation By calling the method startAnimation using the object of View.

Here is my example code. Dont know whether it will be helpful to you or not.

```
overridePendingTransition(0,0);
//finish();
v.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fadeout));
startActivity(new Intent(ContentManagerActivity.this,Mainmenu_activity.class));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be someone still having this issue and not found a solution -even though reads a lot of stackoverflow answers- like me!

So my case was: I used `animatorSet` and

1. there was not a single view that i could call clearAnimation on,
2. I wasn't calling my animation from backgroundThread -which you should never do that, btw-

As a solution, i did call `animatorSet.end()` right before `animatorSet.start()`

Answer (score 0):

When you start an animation command in a view that is partially offscreen, the animation start and the onStartListener is called, but the animation doesn't run completely (somehow it is interrupted in the middle). My guess is that, as the view is offscreen, it is canceled and therefore it's onFinish is not called. As a workaround for that i created my own animation listener that start's an handler and uses postDelayed to notify the user of the animation end event. In Kotlin:

```
abstract class PartiallyOffScreenAnimationListener : Animation.AnimationListener, AnimationListener {
    override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {
        onAnimationRepeat_(animation)
    }
    override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation) {}

    override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation) {
        onAnimationStart_(animation)
        Handler().postDelayed({
            onAnimationEnd_(animation)
            animation.setAnimationListener(null)
        }, animation.duration + 50)
    }
}
```

Please notice that, in the case the animation doesn't run completely, the view may be left at an inconsistent state (for example, animating layout parameters may lead to a weird middle interpolator factor being dropped. For that reason, you should verify at the end callback that the view is in the wanted state. If not, just set it manually.

Comment: what happens if we use this listener and the animation ends properly. Will I get two onAnimationEnd callbacks?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like belows

1. make animation final
2. invoke it inside a handler
3. listener should be instantiated once.
4. clear animation.

for example
view.clearAnimation();

```
new Hander().post(
   run() {
final TranslateAnimation ani = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, 0);
ani.setAnimationListener(mListener);
 }
);

private Animation.AnimationListener mListener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you not setting another animation before that one you are waiting ends?

Without context is hard to understand if it's something like that... but it is probably one of the only things that would cause it.

Comment: No. I'm not setting any other animation. I also have a variable to control this.

Answer (score -1):

I guess Its gets called after sometime becasue you are using setDuration for animation and passing 1000 ms in it. Just pass 0 and it won't take a while to get called.

Answer (score -1):

I tried your code it's working fine at OnAnimation start and inAmimationEnd also , after duration time means after finish  animation onAnimationEnd is called , so your code working fine

```
TranslateAnimation anim =new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, -60, 0);
        anim.setDuration(1000);     
        anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation a) {
                    Log.w("Start", "---- animation start listener called"  );
                }
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation a) {}
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation a) {
                    Log.d(" end  ","---- animation end listener called"  );
                }
            });
            mIv.setAnimation(anim);
            mIv.startAnimation(anim);
```

Answer (score -2):

Where do you start your animation ? If in onCreate, it is wrong. Try to do it in onResume.

Comment: Its not in onCreate, it is called after user interaction.