# Animate removal of an Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

In an app, I try to animate the removal of a Fragment.

```
transaction.remove(fragmentVideo).remove(fragmentProgressBar).replace(R.id.content_pane_calling, endFragment);
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_up);
transaction.commit();
```

The Framework ignores this completely. The Fragment itself gets removed, but the visual is not nice. Any `FragmentTransaction#replace` works well with those animations. I'm using the `SupportLibrary v23.1.`

Thanks for helping me out :)

Answer (score 5):

The call to transaction.setCustomAnimation() has to be called BEFORE transaction.remove()/add()/replace() or the animations will never be run.

So your code will look like :

```
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_up);
transaction.remove(fragmentVideo).remove(fragmentProgressBar).replace(R.id.content_pane_calling, endFragment);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Ah ok.  It seems this question has been asked before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982240/how-to-animate-fragment-removal and you can't actually animate the removal of a fragment as the animation is run on the incoming view.  The question I linked to has some ideas of how to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common issue I used to face. I am very careful when decide to use Fragments at all, since they are very unflexible as for UI animations. You might find an answer here:

http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2013/09/smoothing-performance-on-fragment.html

You could also animate your fragment and execute removal transaction after you are done with animation, doing both things separately in appropriate order.

```
//Pseudo Code

Animation anim = ... //this animates your fragment view
anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

    void onAnimFinish() {
        transaction.remove(fragmentVideo).remove(fragmentProgressBar).replace(R.id.content_pane_calling, endFragment);
        transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_up);
        transaction.commit()
        getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }

})
```